# Adding hyphen in ArcGIS Field Calculator to merge two columns?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, field-calculator

I am trying to build a field calculator expression to merge two columns into one. I am looking for the word that makes it a range.

Example:  I have 2 columns in elevation, `From` and `To`. I want to make them like "`4100 - 4200`" where I add the hyphen. How do I do that ?

[image: table showing data being worked with]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You will want to [concatenate the two fields](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Calculate_Field_examples/00170000004s000000/) together.

To do this in ArcMap you can use the VB Script function "&".  So using your example, the calculation would be

```
[FROM] & "-" & [TO]
```

You could also use Python syntax, in which case your code would be:

```
str(!FROM!) + "-" + str(!TO!)
```

With Python you want to be sure to enclose the fields in the string function -- str()--, so that Python knows you are trying to concatenate two strings together, and not do a mathematical computation.

Comment: just for fun, you could also use the format string python operator: `"%s - %s" % (str(!FROM!), str(!TO!))`, which in this case is more complicated than the above, but is easier if you want to more extended concatenations, e.g. `"Min %s - to - %s Max" % (str(!FROM!), str(!TO!))`