# Concatenate fields in Field Calculator using Python

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, field-calculator, python-parser, error-000989

I'm trying to concatenate fields together and used this post as a guide:
<[Adding hyphen in ArcGIS Field Calculator to merge two columns?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/15561/how-do-i-add-a-hyphen-to-the-field-calculator-to-merge-2-columns/15563#15563)> ; however, I'm still getting a 989 parsing error.  Here's the Field Calculator image:

[image]

I'm just learning python.

Comment: You are correct PolyGeo, this seems to be a duplicate after reviewing those on the link you provided.  I had not seen those previously.

Answer (score 4):

This is the correct script in the Field Calculator:
[image]

This link was helpful:  https://geonet.esri.com/thread/54648?q=concatenate%20text%20fields